# How to dynamically define the Horizontal ending cell of the last Column in a range for reuse in a Google Sheets formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need a formula to dynamically compute the number of empty Columns from the datasets.

Basically I would need the same as the vertical dynamic end row limit but for column.

For example I would need =COUNTA(A1:**A**) but for colums for example =COUNTA(A1:**BZ**) but without absolute reference to the column.

I have multiple datasets with a varying number of columns.
Each dataset also has a varying number of empty columns.

For example:

| Datasets | # Columns | # Empty Columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dataset #1 | 11 | 4 |
| Dataset #2 | 5 | 1 |
| Dataset #3 | 17 | 6 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Dataset #n | 19 | 7 |

I have the followwing formula in Cell A1 as of now:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(B2:K,"<1"))
```

With `=COUNTA(B2:B)` dragged to column J/ Row J2 as so:

[image: Dynamically set the horizontal range to last column's cell]

I don't know if there's a way to set the Horizontal ending cell as dynamic and couldn't find another similar question on SO.

Thank you for sharing the solution if you know one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if lets say you wish to get the dynamic blank column count of the tab `Sheet1`; try:

```
=COUNTIF(BYCOL(INDIRECT("Sheet1!1:"&MAX(ROWS(Sheet1!A:A))),LAMBDA(z,COUNTA(z))),0)
```

Comment: thanks but strange, it returns only 1 in a 23 Columns  Sheet1 sheet (cols A to W) with 17 empty columns. Any update? I'll look into your formula some more too.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/yGldOVQ.png well in the screenshot you can see I have 10 columns in total in tab `Sheet1` with 5 non-empty and 5 empty

Comment: That's working on a new sheet as well on my end: https://i.imgur.com/k6l6E3l.png Not sure why it did not work on the previous one. I'll investigate further on my end. Anyway thank you very much for the solution. I'll look into the logic asa. Be well!

Answer (score 0):

Just found some helping insight here:

### Google Sheets - Index & Match, Multiple Columns, Merge Data Similar to SQL Join - Part 2

https://youtu.be/2T__Yyn_Bdw?t=600

`A1:1` is the horizontal dynamic / open ended reference equivalent of

`A1:A` or `A:A` vertical dynamic / open ended reference.

The `:1` selecting the whole row without ending column reference.